# Comparing a SQL field in Python

Tags: python, sql-server

I am trying to build a selenium test in Python that only executes if a flag is set in a SQL database.

The Value in my database for this particular field is currently "False" so it should be turning the switch on but it is not with my code:

```
connection = pypyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                              'Server=MYSERV\SQL2;'
                              'Database=MyDB;'
                              'uid=sa;pwd=sa')

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT Value FROM SystemSettings where ID = 20063')
for row in cursor:
    if row == "False":
        option = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="divFileProcessingSettings"]/div[17]/div/label/span')
        option.click()
    else:
        break
connection.close()
```

Comment: but after the test for false, you call a method that returns a object (you hope! there's no null check there!!) and then calls the click() method that.  If you run you code under debug do you see it taking that branch? Also, the row returned is an object.  row.Value should hold the result of the query.

Comment: Why would you store system settings in a db? These should be in a config file as part of your project.

Comment: This also has nothing to do with Selenium. This is purely about how to get data from a db and turn it into a boolean or at least create a conditional from it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Real quick, what testing have you done?

Is this `if row == "False":` being executed? Have you added a quick print statement to see if conditional is even executing?

If you've done the above and the conditional isn't executing, have you looked at the output of what `Row in cursor:` returns?

I can't remember off the top of my head, but I believe cursor is going to return a Tuple for you. You need to unpack the Tuple into actual variables than do the comparison. You are essentially doing ('False',)  == "False".

You could test that by simply changing your comparison to row == ('False',)  and that will probably work, but you should probably unpack the Tuples

Try

```
f, _ = row 
if f == "False":
```

Comment: The row == "False" is not being executed. If I print the value of row I see ('False',)

Comment: Also you could flip your conditional around to say if 'False' in row:

Comment: Thanks so much! You're right I was doing ('False',) == "False". Once I changed that it worked!  Thank you again